# How to get preferences values Android

Tags: android

I have a preferences screen in Android with multiple , like PreferenceCategory and EditTextPreference. But how do I access these fields? I searched on Google and came across findPreference, which is deprecated I guess. So how can I find these fields in my MainActivity.class so I can use their values or make onclick events for them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... is Google out of order?

Comment: Nope, but I'm an android-newbie and all of the options I found via Google didn't seem to work for me (e.g. findPreference)

Comment: `findPreference` is deprecated in `PreferenceActivity` but not `PreferenceFragment`, however if you aren't using `PreferenceFragment`, then you have no choice but to use `findPreference` in your activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the code below as an example

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

String strUserName = SP.getString("username", "NA");
boolean bAppUpdates = SP.getBoolean("applicationUpdates",false);
String downloadType = SP.getString("downloadType","1");
```

Note that the first parameter is the **key** and the second parameter is the **default** value to return in case the value is not present.

Answer (score 0):

use shared preferences instead 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html